# Funny XML tag: <brand/>

Tags: php, xml

The XML validates as correct but this odd tag is sitting in the middle of it.

What's it there for? What sort of tag is it? It's not a closing tag

It's bloody nuisance it's buggering up my array grr

```
<cat>
<awCatId>
437
</awCatId>
<awCat>
Chocolate
</awCat>
<mCat>
Full Range
</mCat>
</cat>
<brand/>
<valFrom>
0000-00-00
</valFrom>
<valTo>
0000-00-00
</valTo>
<comAmount>
0.00
</comAmount>
```

Comment: How are you loading the xml into your array? Can you post your code so we can help you handle the empty node?

Comment: It's officially known as an [empty element tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-eetag) according to the XML specification. It is equivalent to `<brand></brand>`. Not sure why it's messing up your array; all XML parsers should understand it just fine.

Answer (score 5):

That's a self-closing tag with no content.
It's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Any tag of the form `<tagname/>` is a self-closed tag. It basically means the exact same thing as `<tagname></tagname>` - an element with no children.

Answer (score 1):

`<brand/>` is an example of a **self-closing tag**, and is equivalent to

```
<brand>
</brand>
```

Many browsers will display the two tags with no content as a self-closed tag instead (display need not match source).